# Assigning a null value to a lists of Complex types in C

Tags: casting

I hope you can help me. I am trying to assign a nullable datetime to a lists of complex types, But I am getting an error like below:

"Error Message:
Specified cast is not valid.
"

This is my line of code. I hope that you can give me clear idea on the issue:

List searchParameters = new List();

```
            foreach (DataTable dt in dataSet.Tables)
            {
                 

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //Add the data coming from Common.SuccessDestinationFile to SearchParameters properties
                    searchParameters.Add(new SequenceModel
                    {
                        MotTXNTS = (DateTime?)dt.Rows[i][1] ?? null,
                        Tool = (string)dt.Rows[i][1] ?? "",
                        OAProcessTS = (DateTime?)dt.Rows[i][2] ?? null,
                        MOModel = (string)dt.Rows[i][3] ?? "",
                        QMFHeader = (int?)dt.Rows[i][4] ?? null,
                        MOJobNum = (string)dt.Rows[i][5] ?? "",
                        OAJobNum = (int?)dt.Rows[i][6] ?? null,
                        MOOPNum = (int?)dt.Rows[i][7] ?? null,
                        REFHeader = (int?)dt.Rows[i][8] ?? null,
                        Sequence_Parm = (string)dt.Rows[i][9] ?? "",
                        Header_Stat = (int?)dt.Rows[i][10] ?? null,
                        SampleSize = (int?)dt.Rows[i][11] ?? null,
                        Source = (string)dt.Rows[i][12] ?? ""
                    });
                }
            }
```

I know you would says that all I have to do is to check for null values before adding but the client is insisting that her requirement is to add the null values in the lists so I would like to ask for your opinion if this case is doable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client agreed to assign a default value for null so this is the solution:

List searchParameters = new List();

```
            foreach (DataTable dt in dataSet.Tables)
            {

                List<DataRow> dtLists = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();

                foreach (var item in dtLists)
                {
                    //Add the data coming from Common.SuccessDestinationFile to SearchParameters properties
                    searchParameters.Add(new SequenceModel
                    {
                        MotTXNTS = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ItemArray[0].ToString()) ? DateTime.MinValue : DateTime.Parse(item.ItemArray[0].ToString()),
                        Tool = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ItemArray[1].ToString()) ? string.Empty : item.ItemArray[1].ToString(),
                        OAProcessTS = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ItemArray[2].ToString()) ? DateTime.MinValue : DateTime.Parse(item.ItemArray[2].ToString()),
                        MOModel = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ItemArray[3].ToString()) ? string.Empty : item.ItemArray[3].ToString(),
                        QMFHeader = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ItemArray[4].ToString()) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(item.ItemArray[4].ToString()),
                        MOJobNum = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ItemArray[5].ToString()) ? string.Empty : item.ItemArray[5].ToString(),
                        OAJobNum = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ItemArray[6].ToString()) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(item.ItemArray[6].ToString()),
                        MOOPNum = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ItemArray[7].ToString()) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(item.ItemArray[7].ToString()),
                        REFHeader = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ItemArray[8].ToString()) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(item.ItemArray[8].ToString()),
                        Sequence_Parm = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ItemArray[9].ToString()) ? string.Empty : item.ItemArray[9].ToString(),
                        Header_Stat = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ItemArray[10].ToString()) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(item.ItemArray[10].ToString()),
                        SampleSize = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ItemArray[11].ToString()) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(item.ItemArray[11].ToString()),
                        Source = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ItemArray[5].ToString()) ? string.Empty : item.ItemArray[5].ToString()
                    });
                }
            }
            //store property values to data table
            DataTable submittedDT = Common.ToDataTable(searchParameters);
```